G1 GC take a long time for Object Copy
My application is a typical Java web application, Java 8, using G1 GC. I have encountered a GC problem. Within 10 minutes after the application is started (when the old generation is gradually increasing), long GC often occurs, but this does not happen during the stable operation stage. The following is my GC log:
{Heap before GC invocations=43 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 5242880K, used 496183K [0x00000006a7800000, 0x00000006a7a05000, 0x00000007e7800000)
  region size 2048K, 128 young (262144K), 54 survivors (110592K)
 Metaspace       used 228219K, capacity 255729K, committed 255872K, reserved 1275904K
  class space    used 24456K, capacity 29030K, committed 29056K, reserved 1048576K
2024-06-20T11:44:47.168+0800: 260.143: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 9.8956459 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 9891.3 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 260143.9, Avg: 260145.0, Max: 260147.2, Diff: 3.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.1, Avg: 8.8, Max: 12.5, Diff: 7.5, Sum: 35.2]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 12.2, Max: 16.2, Diff: 16.2, Sum: 48.6]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 39.2, Max: 69, Diff: 69, Sum: 157]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 1.1, Max: 1.9, Diff: 1.8, Sum: 4.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 4.0, Max: 6.1, Diff: 6.1, Sum: 15.8]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 9855.0, Avg: 9863.9, Max: 9884.8, Diff: 29.8, Sum: 39455.6]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 15.8, Max: 23, Diff: 22, Sum: 63]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.2]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 9887.8, Avg: 9890.0, Max: 9891.1, Diff: 3.3, Sum: 39560.0]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 270035.0, Avg: 270035.0, Max: 270035.0, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 1.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.2 ms]
   [Other: 3.0 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.1 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.5 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.4 ms]
   [Eden: 148.0M(148.0M)->0.0B(234.0M) Survivors: 108.0M->22.0M Heap: 484.6M(5120.0M)->338.4M(5120.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=44 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 5242880K, used 346567K [0x00000006a7800000, 0x00000006a7a05000, 0x00000007e7800000)
  region size 2048K, 11 young (22528K), 11 survivors (22528K)
 Metaspace       used 228219K, capacity 255729K, committed 255872K, reserved 1275904K
  class space    used 24456K, capacity 29030K, committed 29056K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=17.10 sys=0.90, real=9.90 secs] 

I tried increasing the SURVIVOR area, but it didn't work. Here are my JVM parameters:
-Xmx5120m -Xms5120m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=400M -XX:MetaspaceSize=400M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Dnacos.use.endpoint.parsing.rule=false -Dnacos.use.cloud.namespace.parsing=false -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -Xloggc:/tmp1/main-gc.log

What makes you think that this is a GC problem?  It could also be memory leak.  That can cause long GC times too.  And if it is a memory leak, tweaking the JVM parameters will not fix it.

My application has just been started for less than 5 minutes and there is still a lot of memory, so I don't think there is a memory leak problem
http://images.tuodan.tech/operate/20240620/e649f6944b7d415492f49c7520b698ac.png

Sorry ... but we don't read Chinese here so it is not possible to understand those images.

http://images.tuodan.tech/operate/20240621/2f4758325b054127aae6ad8e442e0c1a.png

The issue may stem from other aspects of the G1 garbage collection configuration or the application's memory usage patterns. Here are additional strategies and adjustments you can try to mitigate the long GC pauses:
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4M
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=60
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

Further things to do

Heap Dump Analysis: Capture and analyze heap dumps during the problematic phase to understand what objects are consuming memory. Utilize profiling tools like VisualVM, YourKit, or Java Mission Control to analyze the memory usage patterns and object allocations. My favorite is JProfiler
Monitor GC Logs:
Continuously monitor and analyze the GC logs to identify any patterns or specific allocations that might be causing the long GC pauses. Look for frequent or long G1 Evacuation Pauses
Gradual Increase:
If applicable, gradually increase the heap size to give more room for objects, allowing the GC to work more efficiently.


If it is a heap memory leak Steps to Diagnose
Run your application with the reduced heap size and observe the behavior.
Capture heap dumps at regular intervals, especially when you notice long GC pauses.
Analyze the heap dumps with tools like JProfiler to identify any objects that should have been garbage collected but are still in memory.
Investigate the code paths that lead to the retention of these objects.

I noticed that the heap size barely changed , Heap: 484.6M(5120.0M)->338.4M(5120.0M),  does that mean that some objects are not causing the long pauses?
